# error when loading json data in hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

JSON data looks like :

```
{"id":"U101", "name":"Rakesh", "place":{"city":"MUMBAI","state":"MAHARASHTRA"}, "age":20, "occupation":"STUDENT"}
{"id":"","name":"Rakesh", "place":{"city":"MUMBAI","state":"MAHARASHTRA"}, "age":20, "occupation":"STUDENT"}
{"id":"U103", "name":"Rakesh", "place":{"city":"","state":""}, "age":20, "occupation":"STUDENT"}
```

I get the following error while trying to `select` the data from the table :

```
hive (ecom)> select * from users_info_raw; 
OK 
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException:
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('2'
(code 50)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries  at
[Source: java.io.StringReader@15b0734; line: 1, column: 222] 
Time taken: 0.144 seconds
```

Create Table DDL Query:

```
CREATE TABLE users_info_raw(
       > id string,
       > name string,
       > place struct<city:string,state:string>,
       > age INT,
       > occupation string
       > )
       > ROW FORMAT SERDE
       > 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
       > STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
       > 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
       > OUTPUTFORMAT
       > 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

Comment: Place age 20 in double quotes "20",  hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have used hive hcatalog serde and it is working fine with your input data.

`CREATE TABLE info_raw(
  id string,
  name string,
  place struct<city:string,state:string>,
  age INT,
  occupation string
  )
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';`

[image]